# Pass Python variable to Suubprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm new to Python and I need help with the following problem.

I'm trying to make the subprocess execute the following code so that the sites stored in a variable open in Internet Explorer mode.

```
link = "www.google.com"
def openlink(link: str):
    subprocess.call('"powershell" $ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application')
    subprocess.call('powershell' '$ie.navigate(link)')
```

I get the following error when trying to run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\luiis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\luiis\Desktop\IMPORTANTE\Softwares Luis Teixeira\Portal Links\main.py", line 10, in open
subprocess.call('powershell' '$ie.navigate(link)')
File "C:\Users\luiis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 345, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\Users\luiis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\luiis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado
```

Comment: Don't use quote markdown unless you're actually quoting someone (or some docs). For code, or console output, or stack traces etc. use regular code markdown. Having said that, your error says "filenotfound", which I hope stays true forever: internet explorer no longer "exists" (Microsoft killed it off. You _might_ still have it installed, but it's properly dead, it's not getting any updates, and MS doesn't want you to use it anymore to the point where they've actively pushed out an [update that removes it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows-message-center#2985) =)

Comment: The "filenotfound error" was fixed by entering the full path. I need IE for legacy enterprise sites until they are updated. thanks.

Comment: No you don't? Edge has an IE mode [literally for that purpose](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/internet-explorer-mode-in-microsoft-edge-6604162f-e38a-48b2-acd2-682dbac6f0de). It's part of _why_ Microsoft has actively pushed updates that remove IE from machines, whether you want that or not. Use Edge if you absolutely need a modern browser that can still run ancient ridiculous IE-only pages.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have internet explorer on my machine, but this code does not parse an error:

```
import subprocess

link = "www.google.com"

def openlink(link: str):
    subprocess.call(f'powershell "$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; $ie.navigate(\'{link}\')"')

openlink(link)
```

OR you can have it bypass powershell by just opening with chrome or firefox directly like this:

```
import subprocess

link = "https://www.google.com"

def openlink(link: str):
    subprocess.call(f'start chrome {link}', shell=True)

openlink(link)
```

Comment: Yes, the key thing here is the use of the f-string - whereas OP's original code just includes `(link)` within a plain string literal, so no variable expansion will be done.

Comment: True, but because he's a beginner its nice to know there are a few options to do the same thing. But I see in the original thread he got his answer resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are encountering a file not found error when you try to execute the PowerShell command in your Python script. Usually I've seen this error occurs when the subprocess module cannot find the "powershell" executable file.

To fix this error, you need to provide the full path to the PowerShell executable file. You can do this by modifying the first subprocess.call() line to:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', '$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application'])
```

This should execute the PowerShell command and create a new Internet Explorer application. Next, modify the second subprocess.call() line to:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', f'$ie.navigate("{link}")'])
```

This will use f-strings to insert the value of the "link" variable into the PowerShell command, so that Internet Explorer will navigate to the specified URL.

Make sure to replace "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" with the actual path to your PowerShell executable file.

Comment: This can't be the problem. If it was, then the first call to `subprocess.call` would fail. But the stack trace shows that the second call is the one that fails.

Comment: The code helped me to understand. Thanks. But after running it I get the error:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ie.navigate("https://www.google.com")